# Selenium find element via Data-Qa attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have building my Selenium framework. All the elements need to be found by Data-QA.  I am unsure on how to do this. I have done the pervious using Ids that was simple enough. I cannot find data qa in the find element by

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: what is "Data-QA" ?

Comment: So if I inspect the object
<input _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" data-qa="'input_login_operator'" id="login-operator-field" matinput="" name="operator" placeholder="Operator" required="" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="mat-error-0">

Comment: also for ref: https://www.utest.com/articles/data-qa-attribute-a-better-way-to-select-elements-for-ui-test-automation

Comment: Post an example of your mark-up.  Your question will likely get closed without it.

Comment: Forgive me. Mark-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are extra single quotes in the HTML, inside the double quotes:

```
data-qa="'input_login_operator'"
```

I would remove the single quotes from the DOM, or escape them in the CSS selector.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to find elements with a particular value for a specific attribute.  I don't know C#, but with Python the following should work (I like to use a CSS selector):

```
all_login_inputs = find_elements_by_css_selector("input[data-qa='input_login_operator']")
```

this will return a list of elements that have a tag "input" with the "data-qa" attribute set to the value "input_login_operator"

Comment: If my short experience is correct I should be using

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-qa='input_login_operator']");

I will try tomorrow, thanks. If anyone else can confirm or deny that would be great.

Comment: This didn't work. 

I have also tried 

[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "data-qa=input_login_operator")]
        public IWebElement txtOperator { get; set; }

Comment: please update your question (not as comments) with the relevant HTML code, your selenium code, and the exception stack trace that shows up when it doesn't work.  These are the details that will allow us to help you.

Comment: Sorted FindElement(By.cssselector(input[data-qa=input_login_operator])