# Javascript: Select all data-qa attributes on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using only JavaScript, without the use of JQuery etc, what is the most efficient way to select all attributes names that have a certain data attribute (let's say data-qa).

```html
<p data-foo="0"></p><br/><h6 data-qa="apple"></h6>
<p data-foo="0"></p><br/><h6 data-qa="book"></h6>
<p data-foo="0"></p><br/><h6 data-qa="car"></h6>
```

Expected result should be list :

```
apple
book
car
```

This question gets the parent elements, I want the attributes themselves. [Select all elements with "data-" attribute without using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/select-all-elements-with-data-attribute-without-using-jquery)

**Resources:**

[Selenium find element via Data-Qa attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54352702/selenium-find-element-via-data-qa-attribute)

[Data-QA Attribute: A better way to select elements for UI test automation](https://dev.to/chriszie/data-qa-attribute-a-better-way-to-select-elements-for-ui-test-automation-48lm)

Comment: Once you have the elements, you can loop over them and use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: Also, please don't add irrelevant tags like [ecma]. [ecma] refers to the organization, and it harms the ability for other users to find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works by getting all of the elements using `document.querySelectorAll`, mapping the elements to the values of the data attributes, and then filtering out the ones that are falsy or `'0'`.

```js
let getAllDataAttrs = name => Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(`[data-${name}]`)
  ).map(elem => elem.getAttribute(`data-${name}`))
  .filter(val => val && val !== '0');

console.log(getAllDataAttrs('foo'));
```

```html
<p data-foo="0"></p><br/>
<h6 data-foo="apple"></h6>
<p data-foo="0"></p><br/>
<h6 data-foo="book"></h6>
<p data-foo="0"></p><br/>
<h6 data-foo="car"></h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, below is essentially the core vanilla javascript functionality needed ...

Using `querySelectorAll`, `querySelector` and `getElementById` should get you started.

```js
// get "data-qa" value by "id"
var data = document.getElementById('id-test2').getAttribute('data-qa');
console.log(data);

// get "id" value by "data-qa"
var data = document.querySelector('[data-qa="data-qa-test2"]').id;
console.log(data);

// get all elements with attribute "data-qa"
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-qa]');

// get all "ids"
var data = [];
elems.forEach(function(elem){
  data.push(elem.id);
});
console.log(data);

// get all "data-qa"
var data = [];
elems.forEach(function(elem){
  data.push(elem.getAttribute('data-qa'));
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<div id="id-test" data-qa="data-qa-test"></div>
<div id="id-test1" data-qa="data-qa-test1"></div>
<div id="id-test2" data-qa="data-qa-test2"></div>
<div id="id-test3" data-qa="data-qa-test3"></div>
```