# Javascript: Find all the Grid Column Names

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, kendo-grid

How do I use Javascript to  find role = ColumnHeader below, and then the Text field underneath it (ProductNumber)?

Basically trying to collect all the grid column names into an array, for Test Automation.

[image]

**Resource:**

[Javascript: Select all data-qa attributes on HTML Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129544/javascript-select-all-data-qa-attributes-on-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),

```
 var colHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('[role = ColumnHeader]');
```

It will select all the elements in the DOM with the given selectors.

Now to get all the name of the column header, you can do the following,

```
var colHeaderNames = [];
document.querySelectorAll('[role = ColumnHeader] > .k-link').forEach(item => colHeadersNames.push(item.innerText));
```

Comment: Hi Updated the answer.

Comment: hi, accepted answer and gave points, maybe you can help answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585817/javascript-selector-find-checkbox-for-corresponding-sibling-text